# Missing template arguments before 'L'

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors

Having following errors

```
[Error] missing template arguments before 'L'
[Error] 'L' was not declared in this scope
recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

in this code part

```
   int main () {
   lista L;
   L.crealista();
```

What does it mean?

This is class "lista":

```
template <class tipoelem>
class lista {
public:
typedef int pos;

struct cella {
tipoelem elemento;
pos prec;
pos succ;
};

lista ();
~lista ();
```

Comment: the question is missing all the relevant information and the context. what happens before these 3 rows of code? which language is this?

Comment: C++ code and I have that error at the begin of function 'main'

Answer (score 0):

if we boil this down to basics, you have:

```
template <class T>
struct X{};

int main()
{
    X x;
}
```

since X is a class template, and you have supplied it with no T, you will get an error saying that there are missing template arguments.  The fix is to supply it with the appropriate elements:

```
// ... as before ...
int main()
{
    X<int> x; // Note <int> argument.
}
```

From your brief snippet, it looks like you have a linked list (lista) that you are creating with some data type (tipoelem) you want to store in it.  You need to state to lista what tipoelem you want.

E.g.

```
lista<int> L;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! now i'm trying to implement a printlist function.

Added this in the list class header file

```
void stampalista (lista& L);
```

and in .cpp

```
template <class tipoelem>
void lista<tipoelem>::stampalista (lista& L) {
    lista::pos corrente;

    if (L.listavuota()) {
        cout << "la lista e' vuota\n";
        return;
    }

    corrente = L.primolista();
    while (!L.finelista(corrente)) {
        cout << L.leggilista(corrente) << " ";
        corrente = L.succlista(corrente);
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Error:

[Error] no matching function for call to 'lista::stampalista()'